# cassandra-pdo error selecting composite keys

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, cql3

I'm getting the error below in /var/log/apache2/error.log when selecting data using cassandra-pdo on PHP:

```
[Mon Jan 14 23:37:47 2013] [error] [client 10.0.0.5] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'CQLSTATE[08006] [8] No more data to read.' in /var/www/test_cassandra_pdo.php:13\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/test_cassandra_pdo.php(13): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/test_cassandra_pdo.php on line 13
```

I'm using:

- lastest cassandra-pdo (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/)
- Apache/2.2.22
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:00:43)
- Cassandra 1.2
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Below is my PHP code:

```
// Connect to two hosts
$dsn = "cassandra:host=cassandra001,port=9160;host=cassandra002,port=9160;cqlversion=3.0.0";
$db = new PDO($dsn);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("USE test");

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT page, local, key, vl FROM lalala;");
//$stmt->bindValue(':key', 'a');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

Below is the data structure (created and listed with cqlsh):

```
Connected to test at cassandra001:9160.
[cqlsh 2.3.0 | Cassandra 1.2.0 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.35.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use test;
cqlsh:test> describe table lalala;

CREATE TABLE lalala (
page text,
local text,
key text,
value text,
vl text,
PRIMARY KEY (page, local, key)
) WITH
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
comment='' AND
dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
replicate_on_write='true' AND
compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

The select using cqlsh:

```
cqlsh:test> SELECT page, local, key, vl FROM lalala;

 page       | local | key   | vl
------------+-------+-------+----------------
 teste.html |    EN | title | Ola, bem vindo
```

I opened a issue on cassandra-pdo but without any return:

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/issues/detail?id=15

Anybody can help?

Comment: Still no answer. CQL 3 it's a great tool, but we cannot use it properly in php... :(

Comment: Which rpc_server_type are you using ?

Comment: I'm using: rpc_server_type: sync

Comment: I never used PDO, but with phpCassa (and C+++ thrift binding too) we had to remove the setCqlVersion call... Try to remove the cql 3.0.0 part in the dsn, maybe something will happen... Just guessing here.
In the meantime updating to 1.2.1 could help.

Comment: It don't work too. I think that the cassandra-pdo dont really work with full CQL3. In this time, i changed my approach. I'm using the datastaxs JavaDriver in tomcat, an using the php-java-bridge to comunicate between PHP and Java. It´s working, but need more tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a fork](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO) of [cassandra pdo](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/issues/detail?id=5#c4). I started using it. But not sure if I will move completely to it. I will test how developers reacts to my issues reports. If it will not be actively maintained, I will move back to original pdo from apache and use cql2.
Hope it will not happen, cql3 map type is so useful.

Comment: Good news! Hope this continue maintained. Another doubt, how the connection pool works in cassandra-pdo? The connection is re-established every time the .php script is runned?

Comment: I don't know the answer for your question. P.S. The fork seems to be very good maintained and the developers are responsive. This days we resolved the support for collection types in CQL3. Checkout project page for more information https://github.com/mathieu-lornac/YACassandraPDO